# .NET Core EF polymorphic one to many relationship between multiple models

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, relationship

I've started learning .NET Core. Now, I've bumped into a problem related to one to many relationship.

I have Buildings and Rooms models. Both store images into images table (Images model).
[image]

Here, I'm not being able to do it. How to solve this problem using EF? I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: What's your issue? What you cannot figureout? Could you please share more details about your requirement?

Comment: You should have 3rd table concept of database, which means it would contains your imageUrl and roomId and BuildingId, so that you can figure out, a perticular image URL belongs to which building and room. You can [`take a look here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description#third-normal-form)

Comment: To say it simple, polymorphic associations are *not* supported in EF Core.

Comment: As per my understanding, scenario might be, user would upload an image, under a building for a room. So that, we have to track that,  the image belongs to which building and room. So model design should be, `Building(BuildingId, Name)`, `Room(RoomId, Name)`, `Image(ImageId, ImageUrl, BuildingId, RoomId)`, no mater how you would design your model, if you do otherwise rather then this, your scenario would become complex.

Comment: I just want to implement something described there: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations. That is in php/laravel framework. I want the same in .net core EF.

Comment: @AlisherNasrullayev Yes, some ORM frameworks *do* support such relationships. But EF Core is *not* one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use a single ID for both relationships, where the FK can point to one of multiple different tables, then it isn't something you can do with SQL constraints. FKs can only point to one table.

You likely want to create separate FKs for both of the tables. Make both of the FKs nullable, and only specify one of the two for each image. By seeing which FK isn't nullable, you'll also know the type of the image.

You could also model the relationship as a many-to-many (one-to-many's being a subset of many-to-many's), which would also solve this issue, but you'd need a separate many-to-many table for every table (buildings, rooms, ...). Of course it'd be a performance hit.

Another approach is to create a base table that only includes the common columns shared between buildings & rooms ("Name"). Have your images table FK point to the shared base table. Your derived tables, buildings and rooms, in turn have FKs pointing to their base tables in a one-to-one relationship.

It is also possible to create a single shared table or table hierarchies with [this EF feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance). This allows you to model the hierarchies in an OOP way and have EF translate the classes into DB-level base tables for you:

> In the TPT mapping pattern, all the types are mapped to individual tables. Properties that belong solely to a base type or derived type are stored in a table that maps to that type. Tables that map to derived types also store a foreign key that joins the derived table with the base table.

In case the image URLs are only accessed through buildings/rooms and you don't need to do any special querying, you could also create a JSON field for both buildings & rooms that simply contains a list of the image URLs, bypassing the problem entirely.